# Проверка прохождения 2FA ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, mvc, 2fa

Вот у меня возник вопрос, как лучше реализовать проверку, что пользователь подтвердил `2FA`. Можно ли организовать проверку аналогично атрибуту `[authorize]` (проверка по куки пользователь, авторизирован или нет), чтобы не втыкать везде условия на проверку, в каждом `Action`.

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут `[authorize]` не обязательно вставлять в каждый метод `Action`. Достаточно сделать так, если требуется ограничить доступ ко всем методам контроллера:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //.........................
}
```

Для работы с `Cookie` при авторизации можно почитать [здесь](https://habr.com/post/176043/).